# How do you pass a directory with whitespace into a function as an argument?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I am writing a shell script that will navigate to a specified directory on my computer multiple times through the use of a function, and one of the directories that is specified has two words, and therefore contains whitespace.

I have used `cd "$1"..` for the arguments passed in. I have also tried `cd "$@"` and actually replacing the variable with the actual directory name surrounded by quotes, and the error persists.

```
function Navigate()
{

    cd ~
    cd "$1"
    cd "$2"
    cd "$3"
    open $PWD

}
```

`Navigate "Directory1" "Directory2" "Directory3"`

I keep getting an error message that is showing that the directory can not be found.

**Example:** If the 2nd directory was named `test directory`, the error message would show:

> /Users/Name/Directory1/test and /Users/Name/Directory1/test Directory/Directory3/Directory3 do not exist

Comment: `an error message that is showing` please post the exact error message.

Comment: Just `open "$PWD"`

Comment: Sounds like you called `Navigate dir1 test directory dir2` instead of `Navigate dir1 "test directory" dir3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Navigate()
{

    cd ~
    cd "$1"
    cd "$2"
    cd "$3"
    open "$PWD"

}
```

Put quotes around `$PWD` as shown above and it will work just fine.

When you say `open $PWD`, it expands into `open first_word_of_dir_name second_word_of_dir_name`. This causes `open` to get two arguments, both invalid.